# Tomcat manager application deployed and properly configured but returning 404

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I believe I have properly configured Tomcat to run on port 8080 and have enabled the manager but I get 404 when I try to access it.

**tomcat is running on 8080**

```
$ netstat -apn | grep 8080 | grep LISTEN
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      31068/java
```

**manager WAR is deployed**

```
$ ls webapps/ | grep manager
drwxr-xr-x  5 voops voops     4096 Dec  2 12:34 host-manager/
drwxr-xr-x  5 voops voops     4096 Dec  2 12:34 manager/
```

**manager is properly configured**

```
$ find . -iname manager.xml
./webapps/host-manager/manager.xml
$ tail -4 ./webapps/host-manager/manager.xml
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager"
         privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" antiJARLocking="false">

</Context>
```

**404 when trying to access the manager**

```
$ wget localhost:8080/manager
--2015-04-23 15:03:38--  http://localhost:8080/manager
Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-04-23 15:03:38 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

(same results as above when trying `localhost:8080/manager/html` as well). Note that other applications deployed in the same Tomcat appear to be working properly. Only the built-in manager application seems to fail.